# HttpResponseRedirect url reset

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

Guys this is simple I'm using HttpResponseRedirect when updating an item in the CRUD,

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('catalog/'+category.slugc+'/product/')
```

the url I'm getting is: localhost:8000/catalog/product/1/catalog/snorkels/product/

and I need to get: localhost:8000/catalog/snorkels/product/

can anyone help me!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the prepending `/`

Change

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('catalog/'+category.slugc+'/product/')
```

to

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/catalog/'+category.slugc+'/product/')
```

Another (better way) to do it would be:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url-name', args=(category.slugc, ))) #or reverse('myapp.views.view_name', args=(category.slugc, ))
```

Comment: Reverse won't work because you haven't supplied the required argument to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

First, name your url pattern in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^catalog/(?P<slug>\w+)/product/', 'some.view', name='slug-view')
```

Then, in your views, do the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect('slug-view', slug=category.slugc)
```